# JavaCV examples/tutorial

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

There are a lot of books about OpenCV C++, many examples and etc. But I can't find that on Java. I know the basics like reading, showing images, grabbing frames and displaying them in the loop, but it's so little. I want to do ComputerVision, but all I can find about JavaCV on google are things I mentioned before. Where/How I can learn it?

Comment: A little correction: "JavaCV" is different from "OpenCV Java wrapper". JavaCV is non-official Java version of OpenCV, while "OpenCV Java" is the official Java wrapper of OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for giving better unsterstanding.

Answer (score 6):

The java wrapper is quite young, so there are not many examples on the web. You should get a little understanding of C++ (if you have not already), and use the C++ examples. Many classes/methods are available in the java wrapper, so you can translate them easily.

Sometimes it is a bit difficult to find the appropriate java statement. E.g., all the constants, or the public functions defined in the class Core are directly available in C++ due to the #include statement. In Java, these are public static functions from the class Core, so you have to write Core.xy().

To find the class where a specific constant, or public function is defined, I like to use the [javadoc index](http://docs.opencv.org/java/index-all.html). So, if you want to know where the function `absdiff` is, you search for this string in that index, and find out that it is a static method of Core, so `Core.absdiff(x, y, z)` is the java statement for the C++ statement `absdiff(x, y, z)`.

Comment: I think this will be the only one way to achieve it, so thanks for your answer.